# Hibernate packageesToScan fails, but annotatedClasses works

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

We have a new webapp that we are prepping for deployment.  We changed how we include our jars, from just manually dumping them into the web-inf/lib to using eclipse's deployment assembly to move them from a common location into the web-inf/lib dynamically, creating one repository for our libs.  This tactic works fine with everything but one jar...the one our hibernate entities are in.

The jar is there, we can see it.  It's in the classpath, we can instantiate it.  But when we run, we get an exception for unknown entity as if the annotations from the target entity were never run.  When we replace our "packagesToScan" declaration with a "annotatedClasses" list, it works fine.  Yet our packagesToScan looks right.  I'd much rather use the flexible packagesToScan than has developers required to do the easy-to-forget step of declaring their classes each time.

Anyone have any idea why this might be?

spring config (the below shows all three at the same time, in reality we comment one in at a time):

```
<bean id="rptappSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="rptappDataSource" />
  <!-- works -->
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list><value>a.b.c.report.model.table.BOReportTask</value></list>
  </property>
  <!-- does not work -->
  <property name="packagesToScan">
    <list><value>a.b.c.report.model.table</value></list>
  </property>
  <!-- also does not work -->
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="a.b.*" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.provider">javassist</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show.sql}</prop>
      <prop key="format_sql">false</prop>
      <prop key="use_sql_comments">false</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">K702PRDR</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: BOReportTask is not mapped [from BOReportTask r  where r.reportStatus = :status order by r.submissionTimestamp asc]
      at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:181)
      at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:111)
      at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
      at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:313)
      at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3353)
      at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3237)
      at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:724)
      at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:575)
      at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:292)
      at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:235)
      at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
      at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
      at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
      at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
      at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
      at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:98)
      at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
      at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
      at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1760)
      at a.b.c.report.dao.hibernate.table.ReportTaskDao.fetchByStatus(ReportTaskDao.java:68)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you use org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean and not a newer version (of hibernate / spring) ?

Comment: Maybe the <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" /> helps (sorry for double post - cannot find a way to edit my previous comment)

Comment: @aumand - Re: newer version - We are on hibernate 3.5.1.  We have put in a request to be allowed to upgrade, but aren't authorized to do so yet.  If there is a better class to use within 3.5.1 I am all ears.

Comment: Which spring version are you using and are you jars correctly assembled (i.e. including all the empty directories). In zip file (which a jar is) this isn't always done/necessary however for proper path traversal it is needed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245570/jar-file-add-directory-entries-eclipse-option-while-exporting-jar has some insight into this.

Comment: @aumand - Re: context:component-scan - That's scanning for spring annotaitons, right?  Not Hibernate ones?  anyway, we also use that lower down in our spring config.  It is <context:component-scan base-package="a.b.c.report" />.  I did not include it because I did not think it did anything but spring annotations.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Spring 3.2.  We were not using the "add directory entries" option.  That was news to us, but sounds plausible based on the link.  However, when we did this, things got worse not better.  Suddenly many classes were not found...not just unscanned by annotations, but full-on ClassNotFound exceptions.

Comment: Can you please try to set the packagesToScan property to a directory based package? Like packagesToScan="a/b/c/report/model/table"

Comment: Interesting, not sure why it should start throwing exceptions. But for jar entries to be scanned you need the entries to be there (when extracting it doesn't make a difference but it does when scanning jars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I recently rediscovered this post and thought I'd post the solution for posterity.  When exporting the jars in RAD, the jar wizard has a checkbox called "Add Directory Entries" on the first page of the wizard.  Check that.  Without it, my packagesToScan reference, which was to a root of the package with the entities in it (since there is more than one package of entities), would not be found.  It acted like there were no entitites.  Checking this adds stuff to the manifest and causes the classes to be found by the annotation scanner.