# autowired failed when we import two different jar in context.xml

Tags: java, mysql, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Im tried to import two different jar in main-project context.xml like this

```
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/mini-project-1-context.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/mini-project-2-context.xml" />
```

its failed to autowired with mini-project service, repo. Each mini project have the mysql configuration. Please find my project structure.

```
main-project.war
|
------- main-project-context.xml
        |          |
        |          |
        |          mini-project-1.jar
        |                      |
        |                      ------- mini-project-1-context.xml
        |                      |
        |                      ------- persistence.xml
        |
        mini-project-2.jar
                    |
                    ------- mini-project-2-context.xml
                    |
                    ------- persistence.xml
```

find mini-project-1-context.xml. project name only get changed in another context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.mini.project.one" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mini.project.one.repo" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    depends-on="flyway">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
        value="classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mini-1-DataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Mini1PU" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="project/DS/miniproject1"
    resource-ref="true" id="mini-1-DataSource" />

<bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mini-1-DataSource" />
    <property name="table" value="module1_schema_version" />
    <property name="initOnMigrate" value="false" />
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:db/migration" />
</bean>

<!-- ************ JPA configuration *********** -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Main-project context.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.main.project" />

<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/mini-project-1-context.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/mini-project-2-context.xml" />

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    trace="true">
    <contextScan />
</camelContext>
```

Im getting the following error

```
 12:03:33.894 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#1e5bc130': [entityManagerFactory]
 12:03:33.894 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'service': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>mini-project-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>mini-project-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How did did you export your JAR ? If you export the jar using eclipse you have to explicity click the option 'Add Directory Entries'. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245570/jar-file-add-directory-entries-eclipse-option-while-exporting-jar

Comment: I'm referring this jar through maven dependency. if im add one jar in the sense its working but when im add both jar maven dependency its failed..

Comment: Can you please post the pom here for your main war

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by Defining `transactionManager` and `annotation-driven` in dependency module's context.xml (here main-project-context.xml) and remove `transactionManager` from jar projects (mini-project-1-context.xml and mini-project-2-context.xml).

So **remove** the `transactionManager` and `annotation-driven` from **mini-project-1-context.xml and mini-project-2-context.xml**.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
     <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

and  **Add** the `transactionManager` and `annotation-driven` in **main-project-context.xml**.

```
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <qualifier value="qualifier" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory1" />
    <qualifier value="qualifier1" />
</bean>
```